# Can we get the creation time and date of the file obtained from filestream?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, filestream

I am downloading a file from particular url lets say example.com/file1.txt, the output from the URL is passed through a intermediate layer which access the file as filestream , and my finally i will be receiving the file1.txt as a fileStream , now how will i now the creation date and time of the file1.txt obtained from the URL , i am using c# coding for file operations.

Comment: the most important part is missing, which protocol? **http**://example.com/file1.txt? ;)

Comment: What is it that you want to know the creation date of, exactly? Of the file on the other side of the URL?

Comment: I am using http protocol and i want to know the creation time of the file obtained from that url , please can i know the syntax ?

Comment: The file you saved, or the original web content? There's nothing to say that the content of example.com/file1.txt was ever in a file to begin with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`FileStream` only exposes operations that pertain to the *contents* of a file, nothing more.

For getting meta data, use the `File` or `FileInfo` classes.

However, I doubt you will be able to get the original file meta data, as this is not normally transferred as part of the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can get the details of a file by using the File Object. It has a method called GetCreationTime which takes in the path of the files as a parameter. You can find more information at this website :

[Get File Details](http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-creation-modification-time/)

Comment: He is using a steam, he will be unable to get the metadata from this stream, please read the question again.